# ceiling is leaking directly below second story toilet above... likely issue?

Tags: leak, toilet

I have a ceiling leak (brown wet spot) that is directly above a toilet on the floor above.  There is no apparent leak when just inspecting the toilet including a test flush.  I stopped using this toilet and the stain has still gotten wetter/darker within under 20 hours.
Any suggestions are what are the most likely causes of this?

Comment: Sounds like a water line leak?

Comment: Does the toilet sit solidly on the floor, or can it rock sideways when you put a bit of pressure on it? I'm betting wax ring failure...

Comment: Although you've stopped using the toilet water can still be leaking past the flapper. If you have a crack/leak in the drain pipe then the ceiling will continue to get wet. I would suggest you turn off the water supply valve to the toilet and see if the leak continues. If the leak continues then the problem is a water line leak as indicated above.